# How to get real-time update with antd table in React using axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, antd

I am trying to make my table get real-time update. How to achieve this by using axios.get to execute whenever there is a new result. My implmentation is given below:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, Spin } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';

const TableData = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);

  const fetchRecords = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios.get('config.data_url');
      setDataSource(response.data.files);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      message.error('Unable to fetch records! Try again')
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecords();
  }, []); 

  //columns

  return (
    <div>
      <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} loading={loading} />
    <div>
  );
};

export default TableData;
```

Comment: you can't simply achieve that using `axios`. usually, to get a real time data updates, you'd need to use a websocket connection (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), or server sent events (https://javascript.info/server-sent-events). please refer to the docs of the API you're using and check if they DO provide a real time data.